# css: background-image for tag img doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, css

i have the following script

```
css:
img
{
    background-image:url("man.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-right:5px;
    border: 0;

}
```

it works fine in all browsers, but in IE doesn't.
could you tall me why? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When applying a background image to an `<img>` tag, add `display: block;` to your CSS.